# How to create spring bean with collection data decoupled from parent bean?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, collections

Spring has ability to [initialisate values of core java collection types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements).

I have a complex collection type `Map<String, Set<String>> map`  and it inital value defined in spring config:

```
<bean id="dao" class="ru.mypkg.dao.DaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="TABLE">
                <set>
                    <value>COMMENT</value>
                    <value>INDEX</value>
                </set>
            </entry>
            <entry key="VIEW">
                <set>
                    <value>COMMENT</value>
                </set>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want rewrite my config in next manner: Split it on 2 beans for more readability

```
<bean id="dao" class="ru.mypkg.dao.DaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="map" ref-id="myMap"/>        
</bean>

<bean id="myMap" ..????..>
        <entry key="TABLE">
                <set>
                    <value>COMMENT</value>
                    <value>INDEX</value>
                </set>
            </entry>
            <entry key="VIEW">
                <set>
                    <value>COMMENT</value>
                </set>

            </entry>
</bean>
```

Can I achieve that with no creating additional classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Certainly, using the `<util:map>` namespace. See the [Spring documentation C.2.2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-map).

Another way to create complex configuration is using the [@Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-basic-concepts) approach, or alternatively the [FactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) interface.